# Why would Hibernate's createQuery and createCriteria return a different number of objects?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql, criteria

I have two rows in my table

```
select count(*) from PREFERENCE;

COUNT(*)
----------
2
```

and when I do

```
session.createQuery("from Preference").list();
```

I get two objects.

However, when I do

```
session.createCriteria(Preference.class).list();
```

I get *three* objects - with the first row repeated.

Why on earth would that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [EAGER fetch associations are applied for](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching-custom):

> - retrieval via get() or load()
> - retrieval that happens implicitly when an association is navigated
> - Criteria queries
> - HQL queries if subselect fetching is used

I assume you have one EAGER @OneToMany collection in your Preference entity.

1. The HQL overides the default fetch plan therefore ignoring the EAGET @OneToMany association which will be represented as an uninitialised LAZY proxy.
2. The Criteria query will select the Profile and for each Profile you have two children in your @OneToMany collection so unless you use distinct result you will get two parent rows pointing to the same entity.

   If you want distinct results you have to change your Criteria query to:

   ```
   session
       .createCriteria(Preference.class)
       .setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
       .list();
   ```

Comment: Yes. I see that now. It surprised me a little - essentially Hibernate returns the object representation of what it gets back from the OUTER JOIN SQL statement rather than adapting it into the intention as specified in the Java object. I assumed that the Hibernate session, being a primary cache, would only have one Java object in memory for a given database row. I understand why it does it, now. I suppose I just don't agree with it!